# Laravel check property exist

Tags: laravel, properties, exists

How I can check existing property `$this->team->playerAssignment->player` in more rational way? Now I check it like this:

```
if ($this->team)
   if (($this->team->playerAssignment))
      if (($this->team->playerAssignment->player))
```

Comment: what about `if ($this->team && $this->team->playerAssignment && $this->team->playerAssignment->player)` !!

Comment: I think it is the same. And what if steps will be more than 3?

Comment: You can check it using other `&&` if steps will be more than 3!

Comment: Did you try if(isset($this->team->playerAssignment->player)) ?

Comment: I tried it in laravel blades. And it worked. But in controllers isset($this->team->playerAssignment->player) always return false(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try isset php function.

isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

---

```
if(isset($this->team->playerAssignment->player)){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following has always works best for me:

```
if(isset(Auth::user()->client->id)){
        $clientId = Auth::user()->client->id;
    }
    else{
        dump('Nothing there...');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is

```
if (
    isset($this->team)
    && isset($this->team->playerAssignment)
    && isset($this->team->playerAssignment->player)
){
    // your code here...
}
```

Because PHP will stops if the first is to `false`, if first object exists, it continue to second, and third condition...
Why not use only `&& $this->team->playerAssignment->player` ?! because if player has `0` for value it will be understood as a `false` but variable exists !

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check by null coalescing operator

```
if ($this->team->playerAssignment->player ?? null)
```

Comment: Needs details or clarity

Answer (score 0):

php 8 2024 update here: using the ?-> operator you can do
if( $variable?->prop1?->prop2?->prop3 ){ ...